# How to reuse existing powerforms from demo account to production account

Tags: .net, docusignapi, powerform

Team Docusign,

I want to migrate already created powerforms from demo account to production account, list is huge and don't want to create all powerforms again and link them with templates.

Since I am using powerforms ids in my application, so if I create again in prod account chances are much of errors, since need to update new powerforms id.

Answer (score 0):

PowerForms are generated from DocuSign Templates, which means to migrate from demo environment to production you can migrate the Template then create the powerform link through the UI.  I don't think there's a way to automate the actual generation of each powerform from the template, so unfortunately you need to do that manually, but at least you don't have to re-create each one.

Note that to migrate your templates from demo to production you will need to switch to the **Classic UI** in the web interface (currently template downloading is not supported in the New DocuSign Experience NDSE).

Steps:

1. Login to your sandbox account.
2. Select your profile icon in the top right and click **Switch to Classic**.
3. Navigate to the Templates screen.
4. For a given template highlight it, then under the **Actions** button select **Download Template**

This will in turn download the `XML` definition of that template.  You can then login to your production account and select **Upload Templates** to upload into the account.  Then you can create your PowerForms.